# Bounty offered deleted without any notice

Tags: support, bounties

I had a bounty of 100pts offered on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236865/what-are-some-best-practices-for-large-scale-development-in-python, with a detailed description of why and what would be expected.

The bounty however somehow got deleted (before expiration), with no notice, I was refunded the 100pts, and the bounty description now disappeared into nowhere.

I have contacted SO support with the following answer:

> Stack Exchange Team (Stack Exchange, Inc.)  Oct 16 11:36 (EDT)  It
>   looks like the bounty was refunded by a moderator. I'm not sure why
>   off-hand. The best place to ask would be on Meta Stack Overflow. Doing
>   so will allow the moderator who took the action to comment and explain
>   what happened or why. Please let us know if you need anything further.

It would be nice to at least know what happened. I really want to help improve the answer, and hence the bounty.

Comment: I'm surprised the moderator didn't also close the question while at it.

Comment: @Mysticial We'll just need to resolve that for him.

Comment: Side note, the bounty reason doesn't really make sense here.  It's a polling question.  It's not *possible* to have a canonical answer to a polling question.  That's one of the main reasons we don't like polling questions here.

Comment: @Mysticial - I removed the bounty. I didn't close the question myself, because I wanted to give the community a chance to weigh in on it. I like to give people the opportunity to vote on well-asked questions like this one that may or may not fit the format here.

Comment: @BradLarson Ah. Makes sense. Thanks for weighing in. :)

Comment: The meta effect kicks in.  The question was closed within minutes, and now there seem to be requests to reopen it!

Comment: @oberstet, It was wrong of them to remove the bounty instead of letting it run its course.  I cast the first vote to reopen, we'll see if you get lucky.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: Ok. FWIW and as a note: I still think the bounty description sufficiently narrowed down the original Q - which I also find too broad. But I now won't touch/vote on anything, since I guess it would be bad style to do so. It'll be a learning experience for me to see what happens;)

Comment: @oberstet, yeh, it probably won't get the reopen votes it needs.

Comment: It won't get reopened because it's off-topic <eyeroll>

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I flagged the post, requesting the bounty be removed, because it should be closed as a primarily opinion-based and overly broad question. It is, by today's standards, off-topic.

My flag message read, in full:

> This is an old 'personal experience' polling question; someone put a bounty on it to draw attention, so now I want to VTC it as primarily opinion-based. But, hey, that bounty.. Can a moderator please remove the bounty so this can be closed?

The flag was marked as helpful and the bounty was refunded, after which I voted to close the post. It'll be in the Close Vote queue now, but you may well have accelerated that process by drawing attention to that question here.

Comment: It's also *way* too broad.

Comment: Looks like it only had 1 vote until this question, now it is about to be closed

Comment: @psubsee2003 Well a bounty is to draw attention

Comment: @psubsee2003: And that one vote was mine; I checked while writing the answer, making sure I had not accidentally forgotten to VTC.

Comment: @RichardTingle Questions cannot be closed while they have a bounty on them.

Comment: I don't know Python, but is the ["example"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19332896/250725) answer a real answer, or a pseudo answer to show what the OP here was looking for in the bounty answer?

Comment: @Servy I was joking, I doubt the OP put the bounty on with the intention of attracting close votes

Comment: @psubsee2003: That is indeed not an answer; flagged as such.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I figured that.

Comment: I appreciate your quick response and accept: you are moderators. I don't agree however: it is - in my view - not a poll. Also: please see my bounty description which narrowed down the scope and made it more concrete. And it seems to be interesting to quite a lot of Python developers.

Comment: Don't confuse 'interesting' with 'on-topic'. There are many interesting questions in the world, but only a small subset is suitable to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @oberstet Note we are not moderators, some people here just have enough reputation to cast close votes

Comment: If you had a narrower (on topic) question, you could have posted that as a *new* question instead.

Comment: Can you get my bounty description back? I would like to take this as a basis for making suitable, concrete questions? Would be awesome.

Comment: Indeed, a bounty cannot change the question

Comment: I already took _1_ aspect of the original question and broke it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334483/static-code-analyzer-for-python-catching-module-privacy-hints

Comment: Now, just want to learn: is above Q concrete enough / suitable?

Comment: I answered it, didn't I? :-) It was concrete enough.

Comment: Ah;) Sorry, yes. So I guess it means the Q is ok. Thanks!

Comment: I removed the bounty in response to Martijn's flag to give the community a chance to vote on whether the question was appropriate or not. As I explained above, I didn't outright close the question myself because it was a well-asked question, and I like to allow members of the community to decide for themselves if a question like this is appropriate. The bounty prevented the chance to even vote, so it didn't give that choice.

Comment: Thanks! That resolves the "mystery";) The only thing that nags me is that my original, quite lengthy description of the boundy is lost. Anyway. I can live with that;)

Comment: @oberstet - Unfortunately, I can't seem to find how to get at the history of the bounty notice itself, but this is the follow-on answer you provided: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19332896/19679 . I believe you should be able to see that from that link.

Comment: I agree about deleting my "answer" there since I was really just misusing an "answer" to clarify what I was after with the bounty - and bounty descriptions a) cannot be edited after filing and b) they do not provide syntax markup. I do see my split out Q. No issue. What is lost is my bounty description - I spent some time crafting it.